# Stored Procedure for AlphanumericSequence causing duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm using a stored procedure on MS-Sqlserver 2008 which generates a progressive alphanumeric sequence for storing loads of different data in another table.

But now there is often problems when multiple processes nearly simultaneously access this stored-procedure.

Does anyone have suggestions, how to build it or another idea on how to fix those problems?

Here's the actual code of the SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextAlpha] @s varchar(8) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @res INT;
EXEC @res = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'Upsert_app_lock',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 2000,
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

IF @res NOT IN (0, 1)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ( 'Unable to acquire Lock', 16, 1 )
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    DECLARE @n CHAR(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    DECLARE @pos TINYINT;

    SET @s = (SELECT TOP 1 [CurHighKey] FROM [dbo].[HighKey]);
    SET @pos = LEN(@s);

    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@s, @pos, 1) = 'Z'
        BEGIN
            SET @s = STUFF(@s, @pos, 1, '0');
            SET @pos = @pos - 1;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @s = STUFF(@s, @pos, 1, SUBSTRING(@n, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@s, @pos, 1), @n) + 1, 1))
            SET @pos = 0
        END
    END

    UPDATE [dbo].[HighKey] set [CurHighKey] = @s;

    EXEC @res = sp_releaseapplock
                @Resource = 'Upsert_app_lock',
                @DbPrincipal = 'public',
                @LockOwner = 'Transaction';

END

COMMIT
```

Comment: This question is not related to either Java or C# ... so I've removed those tags.

Comment: Why can you not use the built-in `IDENTITY` columns to generate unique IDs for you? That's exactly what they're intended for; generating unique IDs in a sequence that guarantees uniqueness. Attempting to create your own unique strings like this almost always leads to issues.

Comment: what @SchmitzIT said... or if you want some alpha numerics use a UniqueIdentifier / Guid: 
`CREATE TABLE MyTable(UniqueColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID())`
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: I would defintely advise `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as the default over `NEWID()` unless security is of a high concern (which I am guessing it isn't since the current requirement is for sequential values. [This article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/) by Kimberly Tripp discusses the performance implications of using `NEWID()` over `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`

Comment: My Problem with NEWSEQUENTIALID() is, that i can't limit it to 8 characters, which is the maximum the alphanumeric sequence should have.